# When using a Swal library, I don’t know it got it because of api, why?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

When using a Swal library, I don’t know it got it because of api, why?

```
    async cancelOrder() {
  await Swal.fire({
    icon: "error",
    title: "الغاء الطلب",
    confirmButtonColor: "#d33"
  }).then(result => {
    if (result.value) {
      cancelOrder(this.$route.params.orderId).then(res => {
        router.push({ path: "/orders" });
      });
    }
  });
},
```

Comment: Please, can you explain better what is your question?

Comment: I do not know to take result from API